# Node.js work with (JSON String / Arr?)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on a project running on node.js, but I have never worked with JSON before. I included an API, run a function and got a result returned. When I console.log the result I get this:

```
{ 'Sealed Graffiti | GLHF (Bazooka Pink)': {
    opskins_price: 2,
    market_price: 3,
    opskins_lowest_price: 2
  }
}
```

How do I work with that result? For example access the `opskins_price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    'Sealed Graffiti | GLHF (Bazooka Pink)': {
        opskins_price: 2,
        market_price: 3,
        opskins_lowest_price: 2
    }
}

console.log(obj['Sealed Graffiti | GLHF (Bazooka Pink)'].opskins_price) // output: 2
```